# Android: change update interval of a service running in background

Tags: android, service, sharedpreferences

I have a service running that updates data every x minutes, I want the user to choose the frequency of updates (every 10 minutes, 30 minutes...). I've used sharedpreferences but it seems that the service doesn't change the frequency of the updates.
here is my service code:

```
 public void onCreate()
    {

      super.onCreate();     

      _startService();

     // if (MAIN_ACTIVITY != null)  Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "FileScannerService started");
    }
  /*
     * starting the service
     */
    private void _startService()
    {   

      timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(   

              new TimerTask() {

                    public void run() {

                        try{

                        doServiceWork();

                        Thread.sleep(UPDATE_INTERVAL);

                        }catch(InterruptedException ie){

                            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "FileScannerService InterruptedException"+ie.toString());
                        }

                    }
                  },
                  DELAY_INTERVAL,
                  UPDATE_INTERVAL);

      Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "FileScannerService Timer started....");
    }
```

And here is my sharedpreferences code:

```
         SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
     String interval= SP.getString("synchronisation", "1");
    if(interval.equals("1")) UPDATE_INTERVAL= 30000;
    if(interval.equals("2")) UPDATE_INTERVAL= 60000;
    if(interval.equals("3")) UPDATE_INTERVAL= 120000;
```

I've tried to put the sharedpreferences code everywhere in my service methods but it doesn't work. maybe i'm in the wrong way.
thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: You probably want to use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) for this, since its specifically designed for scheduling things in Android.

Comment: instead of timerTask, is it not the same thing, as there is an update_interval in the timer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to that problem, if you use sharedpreferences to change the update delay of a timer you should do your service work ito the `run()` method and not to call another method. for example: in my code I called the method `do service work()` and when I removed the method call and put the code of this method directly it worked.
hope I've explained it right.